# sp_OACreate POST API call returns Invalid Credentials

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to make an API POST call with a username and password in order to get an authorization token. The token will then be used in subsequent API GET calls to retrieve JSON.

The response for the token will look something like this:
4d9c85fbee217c26664f5a6ea212d852bc993fa51d54f5c67bb04f77ba3b0a3b

I have some C# code that works in retrieving the token, and I would like to replicate the code using T-SQL. When using the code below (which I have borrowed from all over), it keeps returning:

> Status: 403 (Forbidden) Response text: {"code":-1,"error":"Invalid Credentials"}

Here is the T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @responseXML NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @authHeader VARCHAR(8000);   


SET @authHeader = 'BASIC 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF';
SET @contentType = 'application/json';
SET @url = 'http://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/api/v2/login';

-- Open the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP(S) connection.', 10, 1);

-- Send the request.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false', 'username','password';

IF @ret <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @token

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authentication', @authHeader;
IF @ret <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @token

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
IF @ret <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @token

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send'--, NULL, @postData;
IF @ret <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @token

-- Handle the response.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

-- Show the response.
PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
PRINT 'Response text: ' + @responseText;

-- Close the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to close HTTP connection.', 10, 1);
```

The C# code snippet is below

```
<appSettings>
<add key="UserName" value="xxxxxx" />
<add key="Password" value="xxxxxx" />
<add key="ApiBaseUrl" value="http://xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/api/v2/" />
<add key="month" value="202207"/>
</appSettings>
```

and

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private static string _userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        private static string _password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
        private static string _baseApiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"];
        private static string _month = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["month"];


    private static string GetToken()
        {
            var loginDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>
                  {
                      { "UserName", _userName },
                      { "Password", _password }
                  };

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri($"{_baseApiUrl}/login"),
                Headers = {
                    { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" },
                    { "X-Version", "1" }
                },

                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginDetails))
            };
            var token = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return token;
        }
```

Any assistance will really be appreciated.

Comment: T-SQL is totally the wrong place to do this... keep in in C#.

Comment: You can use SQLCLR or the C# language extensions to run your C# from a stored procedure.

Comment: Don't make requests like this in SQL Server, especially with antiquated and leaky and unreliable `sp_OA*` methods, and not even with SQLCLR as suggested above. This kind of task belongs outside of SQL Server in client/helper processes.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, using SSIS a possibility?